# Android contact app with image and can store upto 3000 contacts

Tags: android, image, sqlite, storage, contacts

Iam a beginer in Android. Now I am triying to create an android app. Which has the following requirments,
1.Add/Delete/Update contact
2.Contact contains -Image,Name,Phone,Email,Web site address,Home address etc.
3.Backup and share contact
4.**Must be capable of storing upto 3000 contacts.-Is it possible?**
And my doubt is -Can I store 3000 contacts???
If possible which is the best way?(SQLite or someother external storage)?
How much data can be stored in SQLite by a single apps area?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I store 3000 contacts?

Presumably.

> How much data can be stored in SQLite by a single apps area?

2 TB. You will run out of disk space first. And, before that, users will remove your app, if they believe that it is taking up too much storage. Photos will be your biggest problem area, most likely, as photos tend to take up a lot of space.

> which is the best way?

Asking for opinions is not a good use for Stack Overflow.

Plus, "best" implies agreed-upon criteria (speed of reading data? speed of writing data? speed of searching? storage overhead? ease of programming? ease of synchronizing with a server? security?). Nobody knows what your criteria are. And, in some cases, the only way to determine how different storage options behave would be for you to test them with your specific data.

I would say that SQLite would be the most *common* approach for a contacts database. For example, the contacts database that Android already has uses SQLite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer